# How to use EventBus?

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

In my application i want use EventBus and i added this **dependency**     `implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'`.

I write below codes, but when run application show me force close error and close application!

**My Java codes:**

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void subscribeCancel() {
    prefsUtils.setToShared_BOOL(PrefsKeys.IS_PREMIUM_USER.name(), false);
    navHeader_VipLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    navHeader_notVipLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Show me error for this **line** : `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`

LogCat error :

```
Process: com.app.test, PID: 859
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.test/com.app.test.activity.MainActivity2}: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.app.test.activity.MainActivity2 and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
                                                                Caused by: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.app.test.activity.MainActivity2 and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
                                                                   at org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberMethodFinder.findSubscriberMethods(SubscriberMethodFinder.java:67)
                                                                   at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.register(EventBus.java:140)
                                                                   at com.app.test.activity.MainActivity2.onStart(MainActivity2.java:759)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6973)
```

How can i fix it? please help me

Comment: Where is the code you posted from? Is it really in `MainActivity2`? EventBus is looking there for annotated methods...

Comment: @deHaar, i use this code for post `EventBus.getDefault().post(new SubscribeEventCancle());` . yes i'm sure use this into MainActivity2

Comment: What event are you posting and where do you receive the even with @Subscribe.

Comment: Does your activity have a method `@Subscribe public void onMessageEvent()`? Oh, look at @Khemraj's answer...

Comment: what are you posting ?

Comment: I would suggest you try RxJava instead of EventBus approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `onMessageEvent`, Add this to your `Activity`. Here `MessageEvent` is an modal class, which is passed with Event.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

It is the method where you will get passed data from fired events.